# Help me identify animation short film from late 1980s with angels from film festival

Tags: story-identification, short-film

I saw this short fantasy film at an animation film festival at the [Carpenter Center](https://carpenter.center/) at Harvard University in 1989 or 90, and I have never been able to identify it. Not sure what country, but it was not an American language production.

There was no dialogue, it was beautiful story about a lonely old man who lived alone in valley, he looks out and sees his backyard completely filled with angels. I recall that they are a nuisance to him, and he nails one to the post like a crow. It was haunting and horrifying.

Does anyone know how I find out the name of this short animation?

Comment: lol. That'll learn 'em!

Comment: Have you emailed the Carpenter Center (*ccva@fas.harvard.edu*) and simply asked them for a copy of their programmes for 1989 and 1990? I'm assuming they'll still have them floating around somewhere.

Comment: what a great idea! I know there were a good number of films since it was a festival, but I haven't been able to find a program from that that. It is worth a shot